# Access content os variable line by line in power shell

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I am storing output of a command in a variable.
Now I want to access the content of it line by line.

```
$OutputVariable = (dir | % { $_.FullName -replace "C:\\","" }) | Out-String;
$OutputVariable
```

output is as follows:-

```
D:\ASGN5
D:\ASSIGNMENT 5
```

So basically what i want is to access the output of variable line by line
like first i want to have **D:\ASGN5**

We can have the data by $$OutputVariable[0..n]

But i want to know is there any other way to access it line by line?

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you'd like to do. As the `$OutputVariable` is an array, it can be iterated (look `%`) but it technically isn't line-by-line operation.

Comment: yeah exactly its an array so i have to know before hand length of each line to access it line by line.So I am asking is there any option to get it in line by manner or is there any better way to store the output line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849952.aspx)

> By default, Out-String accumulates the strings and returns them as a single string, but you can use the stream parameter to direct Out-String to return one string at a time.

But you don't have to use out-string at all.
Let use a foreach loop on the object return by the get-childitem (dir) command :

```
$OutputVariable = (dir | % { $_.FullName -replace "C:\\","" })
$OutputVariable |foreach {"value is $_"}
```

Comment: It works fine. But how can i access a specific line number using this command?

Comment: first line : `$OutputVariable[0]` , last  `$OutputVariable[-1]`, a range : `$OutputVariable[0..5]`

Comment: okay..thanks
As I am new to Power Shell, I want to know how Power Shell will treat $_

Comment: `$_` is the current item in the pipeline please have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx